# Unable to create Virtual Environment - 'Nie mo' error

Tags: python, python-venv

I use Visual Studio Code with Windows11 and I want to import pandas module, but when I want to create virtual environment to import module I get eror **'Nie mo'**.

**I use Python 3.9.13** 
I tried to do the same as in the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQGgWnJorw4&ab_channel=StudySession

```
PS Z:\Programowanie\projektzadania> python -m venv zadania1
Nie mo
PS Z:\Programowanie\projektzadania> python3 -m venv zadania1
Nie mo
PS Z:\Programowanie\projektzadania> python3.9 -m venv zadania1
Nie mo
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the venv package using the command

`pip install virtualenv`

Comment: I get such error  `pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
 the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install virtualenv
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Looks like you don't have pip in path, try this instead
```python -m pip install virtualenv```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I installed it using PyCharm and then switched back to VSC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message. The version that you also tried worked for me:
`python -m venv myven` instead of `python3 -m venv myven`